# Visual Studio code annoying auto launch

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio code keeps launching itself randomly and points to a .JS file.
I had to uninstall it because it becomes very annoying.
Anyone had this problem before?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ehy.jpg)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72521

Comment: Thanks , it solved my problem.